# Submit a registration form remotely

Tags: asp.net, webforms, viewstate

A client of mine is needing their current website to tie into an online leasing module off site.

The module needs to be accessed from our website by posting the username and password hash to it, or the registration information.

It works when I copy the view state manually from the source into the form they fill out on our system, but not when I pull it from a WebClient Request.

When I use the WebClient to pull back the viewstate, for some reason, the viewstate never changes.

With each visit in IE though, the viewstate does changes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We were able to force them into submission and create a web service for us to use and a web page that takes a hash to log the user into their system.

Answer (score 1):

Why are you dealing with viewstate? You could authenticate by using WebRequest, get authentication cookie from WebResponse and use this cookie with each next request.

Comment: Due to licensing restrictions, the end user has to be placed on their website.